# Can't connect to remote host from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a database on a remote Google Cloud (GCP) machine. On GCP, I edited the firewall rules to allow access from my desktop and from an AWS EC2 instance. However, the following happens:

From desktop:

```
netcat -zv 35.198.56.213 27017
Connection to 35.198.56.213 27017 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

From EC2:

```
netcat -zv 35.198.56.213 27017
netcat: connect to 35.198.56.213 port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

I don't understand why I can connect from my desktop but not from the EC2. Both IPs are allowed (using the instance public address). The outbound rules for the EC2 instance are allowing all traffic.

Any tips?

**Edit**: I am trying to connect to a mongo instance that is running on port 27017. The `bindIp` on `/etc/mongod.conf` is correctly set to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Does `tracepath HOST -p PORT` help identify the problem?

Comment: @saedx1 I'm not sure, but it looks fine to me. No errors.

Comment: If your ec2 instance is in a private subnet, it's outgoing IP will be the of the NAT gateway, even if it has a public IP.

Comment: I guess this means AWS does not give internet connection by default? I'd have to create a NAT, which comes with its own costs.

Comment: You have outbound internet access by default in a public subnet (i.e. a subnet that has a route to an internet gateway). But if you placed your EC2 instance in a private subnet, then you need a NAT component (e.g. NAT gateway) in order to have outbound internet access.

Comment: My assumption is that you can connect to your instance from your local machine through SSH using it's public IP; so I'm not sure if that's a Public/Private subnet issue.

Comment: Well, after all these days, I could not come up with an explanation/solution. I am not willing to pay any NAT service, thus I can not tell this would resolve.